# JDBC ERROR : AbstractMethodError: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.createArrayOf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array

Tags: javascript, java, sql-server, jdbc

Hi am just selecting Data from SQL SERVER and stroing it in Result set.
I am getting below error.

```
**JDBC ERROR : AbstractMethodError: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.createArrayOf(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/sql/Array**
```

The problem with this below line

```
    java.sql.Array sqlarray = sqlcon.createArrayOf(null, rowValues.toArray());
```

I am not sure why this issue occurs and what exact parameter should I pass createArrayOf().. Please help for this below issue

Here is full my code

```
    public void getDatafromsql(ArrayList rowValues) throws SQLException,ClassNotFoundException 
    {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    System.out.println("SQL Server Start Connecting ");
    Connection sqlcon = DriverManager
            .getConnection(s_url, s_username, s_password);
    System.out.println("Sql server Connection valid");
    System.out.println(rowValues);
    PreparedStatement s1 = sqlcon.prepareStatement("SELECT TOP 6 myid,document,name FROM table1 where DATEMODIFIED between ? and ? and myid in (?)");
    s1.setTimestamp( 1,V_DOC_LAST_REFRESH_TIMESTAMP);
    s1.setTimestamp( 2,V_DOC_CURRENT_REFRESH_TIMESTAMP);
    //Below line throwing error
    java.sql.Array sqlarray = sqlcon.createArrayOf(null, rowValues.toArray());
    s1.setArray(3, sqlarray);
    sql_rs = s1.executeQuery();
    setdataOracle(sql_rs);
    System.out.println("SQL Server Storage Completed ");
    sqlcon.close();
    }
```

Comment: Which JDBC driver version are you using. AbstractMethodError is indicating an unimplemented method

Comment: Does SQL Server even support arrays?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server JDBC driver doesn't support that method:

```
public java.sql.Array createArrayOf(String typeName,

        Object[] elements) throws SQLException {

    // Not implemented

    throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException(SQLServerException.getErrString("R_notSupported"));

}
```

https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerConnection.java

Instead use [Table Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-table-valued-parameters), or pass the data as [XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-type-and-columns-sql-server), [JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server), or [CSV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) and parse it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried call

```
sqlcon.createArrayOf("INT", rowValues.toArray());
```

or

```
sqlcon.createArrayOf("integer", rowValues.toArray());
```

or some data type your data base system supports.
If nothing works, probably the driver you use does not support arrays.
In this case create placeholders (?) "hard coded" and use

```
s1.setInt(i, intValue);
```

in a loop (where i is 3 to (array size + 3)) instead of

```
s1.setArray(3, sqlarray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example how to use table valued parameters as a solution for SQL Server since createArrayOf() is not supported yet.

```
private void createTableType() throws SQLException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try(Statement stmt = DBUtils.dbConnect().createStatement()){
        stmt.executeUpdate("IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.types WHERE is_table_type = 1 AND name = 'Codes' ) " +
                "BEGIN CREATE TYPE dbo.Codes AS TABLE (Code VARCHAR(25)) END");
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        if(e instanceof SQLException){
            DBUtils.printSQLException((SQLException) e);}
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}

public void tableValuedParamQuery(List<String> params) throws IOException, SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        createTypeTable();
        SQLServerPreparedStatement ssps = (SQLServerPreparedStatement) dbConnect().prepareStatement(
                "SELECT * FROM dbo.Products p" +
                     "INNER JOIN ? AS c ON c.Code = p.Code"
        );
        SQLServerDataTable dt = new SQLServerDataTable();
        dt.addColumnMetadata("Codes", Types.VARCHAR);
        params.forEach(e -> {
            try {
                dt.addRow(e);
            } catch (SQLServerException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        ssps.setStructured(1, " dbo.Codes", dt);
        ResultSet rs = ssps.executeQuery();
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e){
        if(e instanceof SQLException){
            DBUtils.printSQLException((SQLException) e);}
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```